# What is minimal application iOS version for publication in AppStore?

Tags: ios, app-store, publish

I try to publish my app to AppStore.
Customer want to know

> What is minimal iOS version application can supporting in AppStore?

How I can find information about minimal  iOS version, which application may support by Apple Rules? 
In AppStore Review Guidelines there is no info about this.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#hardware-compatibility "Apps should run **on the currently shipping OS** and may not use deprecated or optionally installed technologies (e.g. Java, Rosetta)" and https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements "Apps may only use public APIs and **must run on the currently shipping OS**."

Comment: ceejayoz, thanks for answer. So, if I publish my app now, it will support only iOS 11.x?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why not tell us what you wish to support and then we can tell you if it can be done or not. What version of Xcode do you wish to use? What programming language? Of course you should be using the latest version of Xcode (currently 9.2 not counting beta) and you should be using the last SDK (currently iOS 11). With that you can support back to iOS 8.0. But there's little reason to support iOS 8 or even 9 at this point for new apps.

Comment: holex, when you were publicized app last time?

Comment: Minimum version is no specified. I know some products still supporting iOS4, and i guess available through appstore for first generations of iPhones. But you had to support latest version (iOS11) .

Comment: @GolovanovDmitrii It *must* support iOS 11. It *can* support all the older iOSes if you want to put in the work.